# Javascript .each function acting abnormally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
function Overlap() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".overlap").each(function(index, object) {
        var image = $(this).prev().attr('src');
        target = $(object);
        var xmlhttp
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                xresponse = xmlhttp.responseText.split('-');
                $(target).children('a').attr('href', xresponse[0]);
                $(target).children('.name').html(xresponse[1]); //Set returned array appropriately
                $(target).children('.age').html(xresponse[2]);
                $(target).children('.specialization').html(xresponse[3]);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'factory/operational.php', true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send('overlap=overlap&image=' + image);
    });
}, 1000);
```

}

Html:

```
<div class="Divbox" id="Box_three"><img src='<?php ?>' />
    <div class="overlap">
        <a href='' class='name'></a>
        <div class='age'></div>
        <div class='specialization'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it is called by this

```
window.onload = Overlap();
```

From the page that uses it
The problem is the function works .. it is usually called properly and i put the 
window.onload & setTimeout functionality to make sure that the page loads fully before trying to grab the .overlap element. 
Now what is wrong is when overlap is called there are about 48 of the .overlap div element on the page and they all send this request to the operational.php page but, on arrival back they do not appropriate properly, they only appropriate on the last element that comes back from operational.php, can someone help me find the right selector instance to pass to make sure that each instance of the overlap and is children receives the response accordlingly

Comment: What is your HTML structure?

Comment: Shouldn't your function be called with `window.onload = Overlap;` instead? Because in your case, you're having the function run immediately, and not when the page is loaded, as you intend; and you're setting `window.onload` to the return value of your function.

Comment: If you go this way (48 ajax request per second per client seems a bit too much...), you should set a timeout in the success function of your ajax call instead of using an interval to avoid overlapping requests.

Comment: @plalx This question is in no way a duplicate of that question. jQuery's $.each uses a closure thus avoiding that issue. If anything it should be closed due to typo.

Comment: i want the func to load as soon as the page is ready, because if it runs before, it would not find .overlap html element to grab

Comment: @user3629623 That's what the dom ready or window load events are for. But LaughDonor has pointed out why it isn't working. Fix that and you won't need the setTimeout. Better yet, since you're using jQuery, `$(function() { Overlap(); })`.

Comment: Guys! ... it's working already check below for the solution, i should have put var in front of the target = $(object);

Comment: thumbs up my question for reps ... ;) ... thanks everyone .. +Kevin B

Comment: @KevinB It's exactly the same loop/closure issue. All callbacks did close over the same global `target` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you missed declaring your target variable, making it global.

```
target = $(object);
```

should be

```
var target = $(object);
```

without `var`, every iteration of the loop will use the same `target`, meaning all xhr request complete callbacks will use the same target.

Example:

```
$.each(["a","b","c"], function(i,val) {
    x = val;
    console.log(x); // "a", "b", "c"
});
console.log(x); //"c"
```

After the each is complete, `x` will be a global var that contains the value from the last iteration. In your code, you're performing an asynchronous action on each iteration, meaning, the callbacks for each action will happen *after* the each is complete, which is why `target` points to the last iteration for all of the callbacks.

Comment: Super correct! .. i think it just worked! ... please explain this shit!

Comment: I updated it with a basic explanation, is that enough? Not sure really how to explain it any further other than pointing to your code

Comment: not quite enough ... it seems to me like if var were not there once instantiated would be forever but every stop at var means new instantiation ?

Comment: Kinda understand it a byte !

Comment: @user3629623 If this solved your problem, be sure to click the checkmark below the up and downvote buttons so that the question will look "answered" to everyone else.